# I am generating reports using Pentaho BI server, For .doc files

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-design-studio, xdocreport

In that report type , I am able to generate an report for both .pdf and .xls files .. Now I am not able to get the report for .doc files. So please anyone help me out for this.. I am not getting what parameter i need to pass for that .doc file generation using Pentaho BI-Server

Answer (score 0):

Pentaho Reporting does not support DOC files. Use RTF for the closest equivalent of it.